# zeros of solutions of differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the equation $$\left(\frac{1}{1+t}x'\right)' + (1+ \sin{t})x = 0 $$

$a)$ Show that every solution of the equation has at least one zero in $ [0,\pi].$

$b)$ Show that there is a solution having at least two zeros in $ [0,\pi ].$

$c)$ Is it possible for any solution to have more than two zeros on $ [0,\pi ].$

I solved $(a)$ by Sturm Picone comparison theorem and also for part $(b)$ can we take directly zero solution?

But I have no idea about part $(c)$ Can anyone help?

Comment: I assume taking the zero solution trivializes the question, so I doubt it.

Comment: @AndrewD Although technically, the zero solution is a perfectly acceptable answer to part b. I'd be unhappy if it didn't receive full credit.

Comment: @user7530 I agree, but it hardly seems to be in the spirit of the question.